# How to read and write specific number into text in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python I have a two large text files(an input and an output).
I want to read some float values from output(x3,x5,x6) and write those values to specific parts instead of old values(y1,y3,y5) into input.
I have a project and I must write a script for this work. I need your help. I try to do that like below, `python` but it does not work.

```
  a='Flux'

with open('data.txt',"r+") as f:

with open('output.txt',"r+") as f:    
for line in f:
   if a in line:
       for line in f:
           print line
           break       

     f.close()

  output

  ....

  ....

  [flux][1]

        x1            x2          x3        x4           x5          x6
  1  1.3669E+01  4.9079E-01  7.4414E-03  4.2656E-01  9.4185E-02  1.2263E-01  
  2  1.3828E+01  4.9120E-01  7.4390E-03  4.2583E-01  9.4543E-02  1.2313E-01  
  3  1.4079E+01  2.6339E-01 -4.0824E-09  4.2471E-01  3.9748E-03  0.0000E+00  
  4  1.4302E+01  1.7203E+00  4.9458E-01  4.2361E-01  1.2888E-02  0.0000E+00  

input

 ....
 ....
     y1            y2          y3          y4            y5          y6

0.734200E+00 0.734200E+00 0.265800E+00 0.449764E+02 0.575000E+03 0.107900E+04
0.000000E+00 0.216415E+00 0.225200E-02 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00
0.109465E+01 0.667600E-01 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.343321E+00
0.694839E-03 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.155423E+01 0.947885E-01
0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.237800E-04 0.000000E+00 
0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 
0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.333841E+02 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 
0.000000E+00 0.154468E+04 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00
```

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to accomplish?  Are the inputs and output what you want to happen, or are they what is (incorrectly) happening now?

Comment: i am confused, reading OUTPUT and writting INPUT is weird, isn't it the opposite ?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear. I have two code programs, firstly the script read the output (first code's) and then write into input(second code's). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is it electron density of ionosphere?
So i think the best way is to split each line of output and input files and construct new output. smth like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open('1.txt',"r+") as in1:
    with open('2.txt',"r+") as in2:  
        with open ('newout.txt','w') as newout:
            inlines1 = in1.readlines()
            inlines2 = in2.readlines()

            for i,j in inlines1,inlines2:
                buff = []
                i = i.split()
                j = j.split()
                buff.append(i[1]) #or any elems you want
                buff.append(j[2]) #or any elems you want
                buff = ' '.join(buff)
                newout.write('%s\n'%buff)
```

here is example of inputs and outputs:

```
$ cat 1.txt 
1 3 5 7 
2 4 6 8


$ cat 2.txt 
2 4 6 8  
1 3 4 6


$ cat newout.txt 
3 6
4 4
```

Comment: `with open('1.txt',"r+") as in1,open('2.txt',"r+") as in2, open ('newout.txt','w') as newout`

Comment: You can also just `for i,j in in1,in2:` and forget about readlines avoiding reading all into memory.

Comment: Thanks your work - mikebutrimov, , it's a neutronic c-s calculation. But I dont need third txt, The script program firstly read x3,x5,x6 values from output, and the write into input file instead of y1,y3,y6. in my program, I use " if a in line" to find specific parts(x1,x2,x3,x4,...), but after this point I want to read just X3,x5,x6 and write instead of y1,y3,y5. And also I need to use formatted float numbers not integer.